# PeekMessage triggers WndProc callback

Tags: c, winapi, msdn, internals

Yesterday I encountered the weirdest problem I have ever seen.
I wrote a module that should get a notification on USB plugs.
To do so, I created a dummy window and registered it to device change notifications using some interface's `GUID`.

The strange error occurs when `PeekMessage` is called.
at this point, some why, the window's WndProc callback is called, only when the peeked message is `WM_DEVICECHANGE` (we were registered to in the above code).
On any other message, the DispatchMessage triggers the callback, as expected.

code:

```
NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = guid;
not = RegisterDeviceNotification(
    hWnd,     // events recipient
    &NotificationFilter,        // type of device
    DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE // type of recipient handle
);
```

In order to incorporate this module with the rest of my code which is asynchronous, using `Reactor` design pattern with `Windows Events`, and following the advice of stackoverflow community members, I incorporated `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` in order to listen for events and windows messages as well.

code:

```
for (;;)
{
    dwRetval = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(cntEvents, arrEvents, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
    switch (dwRetval)
    {
    case WAIT_FAILED:
        // failed. TODO: status
        break;
    // TODO: handle abandoned.
    default:
        if (dwRetval == cntEvents)
        {
            // Message has popped.
            BOOL x = PeekMessage(&tMsg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE); <---- WM_DEVICECHANGE triggers the callback
            if (x)
            {
                TranslateMessage(&tMsg);
                DispatchMessage(&tMsg);
            }
        }
        else if (dwRetval < cntEvents)
        {
            // event signaled
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: status. unexpected.
            return FALSE; // unexpected failure
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

I disassembled the code, and compared the registers before any call to `NtUserPeekMessage`

Registers on successful call:

```
RAX = 00000059A604EFB0 RBX = 0000000000000000 RCX = 00000059A604EF18
RDX = 0000000000070C62 RSI = 00000059A604EF18 RDI = 0000000000070C62
R8  = 0000000000000000 R9  = 0000000000000000 R10 = 00007FF71A65D800
R11 = 0000000000000246 R12 = 0000000000000000 R13 = 0000000000000000
R14 = 0000000000000000 R15 = 0000000000000000 RIP = 00007FF954562AA1
RSP = 00000059A604EE70 RBP = 0000000000000000 EFL = 00000200
```

Registers on unknown callback trigger call:

```
RAX = 00000059A604EFB0 RBX = 0000000000000000 RCX = 00000059A604EF18
RDX = 0000000000070C62 RSI = 00000059A604EF18 RDI = 0000000000070C62
R8  = 0000000000000000 R9  = 0000000000000000 R10 = 00007FF71A65D800
R11 = 0000000000000246 R12 = 0000000000000000 R13 = 0000000000000000
R14 = 0000000000000000 R15 = 0000000000000000 RIP = 00007FF954562AA1
RSP = 00000059A604EE70 RBP = 0000000000000000 EFL = 00000200
```

**The registers are exactly the same!** (No parameters are passed on the stack, 64bit..)

In both cases (*strange error* and *expected flow*) I stepped into at `NtUserPeekMessage`, it turns out that the `WndProc` callback is triggered only from the internal syscall!

```
00007FF954562A80  mov         r10,rcx  
00007FF954562A83  mov         eax,1003h  
00007FF954562A88  syscall
```

I couldn't find any documentation on MSDN or explanation on the internet to the phenomenon.

I would really like some help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: WM_DEVICECHANGE is always sent, never posted.  SendMessage() does not arbitrarily interrupt the UI thread of a program, that would cause horrible re-entrancy problems.  It needs to wait until it gets a signal that the thread is idle and a direct call to the window procedure isn't going to cause any trouble.  Get/PeekMessage() is that signal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is as expected, and is documented. `PeekMessage` is one of the functions that dispatches sent messages. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx):

> Dispatches incoming sent messages, checks the thread message queue for a posted message, and retrieves the message (if any exist).

And then later in the same document:

> During this call, the system delivers pending, nonqueued messages, that is, messages sent to windows owned by the calling thread using the SendMessage, SendMessageCallback, SendMessageTimeout, or SendNotifyMessage function.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) for `SendMessage` says this (with my emphasis):

> If the specified window was created by the calling thread, the window procedure is called immediately as a subroutine. If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure. Messages sent between threads are processed **only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code**.

By message retrieval code the documentation means functions like `GetMessage` and `PeekMessage`. There are a few others, I don't have a comprehensive list at hand.

Comment: thanks you for the fast reply. I don't quiet understand: how does peekmessage chose whether or not to dispatch the message by itself? by writing `Messages sent between threads are processed` does they mean that this message was sent from another thread (Kernel thread?) to notify about USB plug?

Comment: @CodeNinja It dispatches **sent** messages.  `PeekMessage` retrieves **posted** messages.

Comment: Thanks you David! it makes so much sense now. How would you recommend me registering `Windows Messages` whether sent or posted to my MsgWait loop?

Comment: That's up to the sender. Some messages are always sent, some always posted. WM_DEVICECHANGE is a sent message. WM_MOUSEMOVE is a posted message. Different classes of messages are delivered in different ways.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so is it impossible to remove a sent message from the queue via `PeekMessage(..., PM_REMOVE)`? Only messages that have been posted?

Comment: @Mark Sent messages don't ever get placed in the queue

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for response, I should have phrased that slightly better - "is it not possible to prevent a sent message being dispatched via PeekMessage and PM_REMOVE"?

Comment: @Mark Sent messages don't ever get placed in the queue. That's all you need to know to understand this.